# Should two separate methods that call a shared base method individually validate inputs?

Tags: c#, .net, validation

Say I have a base method `GetSong()` that fetches songs from a database, and two methods that call this - `GetRockSong()` and `GetPopSong()`.

Both methods take a string input of the song name, then pass that input to the `GetSong()` method, along with a genre.

Should the base method be in charge of validating the string input?

I would think the first two methods should, but this would lead to repeating the exact same code (i.e. checking the string isn't empty).

Obviously I have used a hugely simplistic illustration, but the problem is pretty much the same.

Example code:

```
public Song GetRockSong(string title)
{
    // could null check title here before calling the method?
    return GetSong(title, "Rock");
}

public Song GetPopSong(string title)
{
    // could null check title here before calling the method?
    return GetSong(title, "Pop");
}

public Song GetSong(string title, string genre)
{
    // example validation, if null checking title above 
    // then could just check genre here
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(genre))
    {
        // fetch song logic here
    }

    // etc
}
```

Comment: If there isn't anything unique about the title associated with either of the specific methods (i.e only Pop songs can have numbers in them and Rock songs can't  (I know bad example)) then I don't see why you couldn't just do validation in the shared method.

Comment: I would say checking in the `GetSong()` is the way to go. Not only because you cut down on the number of checks, but also avoids depending on the other two methods to provide you correct input.

Comment: @BenKrueger yeah the validation would be exactly the same for both methods

Comment: It depends. If you don't need to process the input in its validated form in the two methods, you can simply delegate this task to the common method. If you need, you can write a validation method and call it from the two. DRY-don't repeat yourself. On the other hand simple checks, like NullOrWhitespace might worth repeating in more complex scenarios.

Comment: @ZorgoZ in the project I'm working on there is a validation method that essentially null checks the value provided. this method is used to validate all the strings and other types of input.

I suppose I just don't think I should be using this ValidateInput(x) method multiple times in both seperate methods when I could consolidate them in the shared

Comment: If the code is complicated enough in GetSong, and the validation is complicated enough, you could even split it into one function that validates the arguments (and returns a bool on success) and then a second function, GetSong that does the work if the validation succeeded.  Of course, "it depends".  But, yes, if you have code that is exactly the same that's needed in two places, refactor it out into a common method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally think if the validation is the same then do the check in the shared method. 
This will allow for you to maintain the code easier and it is always best to have the method that does the heavy lifting also validate the values passed to it.

I have done similar thing and found that the amount of code I needed to write and maintain is half of what it could have been if I had put the validation in each method that called it.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, seems like this is the general opinion!